# Adding a second endRequestHandler in a .NET web application

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, request

I'm a newbie in C# language and I'm quite lost trying to extend an already existent and non-mantained .NET web application.

The application has a `Web User Control` with a button that, when clicked, refreshes its inner content through this piece of JavaScript code within the .ascx:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var btnId = '<%= btn.ClientID %>'
    if (sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id == btnId) {
        // loads a popup with the new content
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. The problem comes when I try to add a new `Web User Control` which does practically the same, but of course through a different button and loading different content. I replicated the code structure, both in the front and in the back, but I cannot get the second `endRequestHandler` to execute:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandlerStats);

function endRequestHandlerStats(sender, args) {
    alert("I'm here!");
    var btnStatsId = '<%= btnStats.ClientID %>'
    if (sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id == btnStatsId) {
        // loads another popup
    }
}
```

Suprisingly, that `alert` pops when the first `btn` is clicked, but not with the second `btnStats`.

I think the problem is caused because the `btnStats` doesn't trigger a request, but as I said I am new at this and I have no idea why. And the operation is done properly, the only thing that doesn't work is what is done in that script. Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is what the if condition is for - it is to check which button was clicked. The event model of JavaScript doesn't allow multiple handlers to be attached (at least not without some extra work), so this is probably the next best thing.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);

function endRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var btnId = '<%= btn.ClientID %>'
    var btnStatsId = '<%= btnStats.ClientID %>'
    if (sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id == btnId) {
        // loads a popup with the new content
    } 
    else if (sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id == btnStatsId) {
        // loads another popup
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too, but still nothing. That `sender` parameter doesn't get anything if the sender is `btnStats`. That's why I think the request handler is ignoring it.